# How to convert a string to date with UTC/GMT timezone

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that receives a string in this format:"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss" from my server. I want to convert this string to a Date object with UTC as timezone since the time in the string is UTC. I've already checked several similar questions but didn't find my answer

Here is what I'm using currently:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            try {
                date = format.parse(itemContent [3]);
                entity.setValidTill(date);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
```

But what it does when I print that date with Log is show it as:

> Sun Aug 27 15:00:00 GMT+04:00 2017

I want it to be:

> Sun Aug 27 15:00:00 GMT 00:00 2017

So here is the main question how to get DateTime for UTC using a string with format as above?

Edit:

Just put it in a better context. I'm trying to get users to see the difference between current datetime & the that datetime saved in server. So my solution was to get gmt time for users & compare with the server time(which is gmt) so everyone see same difference regardless of their timezone. With C# you can get DateTime.UtcNow while with java I couldn't find an alternative

Comment: [`DateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-) (before you parse).

Comment: Is your issue with printing the date or persisting it?

Comment: Please check my edit. I've explained a bit what I'm aiming with to do with this

Comment: Do you know what time  zone is intended but not labeled in that incoming string? Is it UTC?

Comment: These issues have been covered *many* times already on Stack Overflow. Search for class names LocalDateTime, Instant, OffsetDateTime, ZonedDateTime, ZoneOffset.UTC, ZoneId, and the project ThreeTenABP for Android, and the ISO 8601 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, as your Question is really a duplicate of many others…

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Parse your input string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as it lacks any indicator of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

Define a formatter to parse your input string.

```
String input = "08-27-2017 15:00:00" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2017-08-27T15:00

A `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment on the timeline, only a rough idea about a range of possible moments. Has no meaning without the context of an offset (or time zone).

If you are certain that input was intended for UTC, assign the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` for a `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2017-08-27T15:00Z

To calculate a delta between that moment and the current moment, use the [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class for coarser granularity in your span of time, or [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) for finer granularity. Both classes generate strings in standard ISO 8601 format of [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

```
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
Duration d = Duration.between( odt , now ) ;
```

> now.toString(): 2017-08-27T21:16:56.396Z
>
> d.toString(): PT6H16M56.396S

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DJGODe).

In the standard strings seen above, the `Z` is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

just add this code under the first line of your code:

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: The datetime coming from server is already in UTC. So setting timezone will add 3 hours to time in my timezone